# How to get a sum of some closures

Tags: ios, swift, escaping, closures

2 simple functions with escaping closures

```
func A(closure: @escaping (Int) -> () {
       //some delay
         closure(value1)
    }

func B(closure: @escaping (Int) -> () {
   //some delay
     closure(value2)
}
```

In other function I need to get sum of value1 and value2

for example

```
func sum(completion: @escaping: (Int)->()){
     A(closure: { value1 in
        B(closure: { value2 in 
           sum = value1 + value2
           completion(sum)
        })
     })
}
```

But I don't understand what to do if I need to sum results of many functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DispatchGroup`

```
    func a(closure: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
       //some delay
         closure(value1)
    }

    func b(closure: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
       //some delay
         closure(value2)
    }

    func c(closure: @escaping (Int) -> ()) {
       //some delay
         closure(value3)
    }

    func sum(completion: @escaping: (Int)->()){
        let g = DispatchGroup()
        var sum = 0
         g.enter()
         a(closure: { value1 in
            sum += value1
            g.leave()
         })
         g.enter()
        b(closure: { value2 in
           sum += value2
           g.leave()
        })
         g.enter()
        c(closure: { value3 in
           sum += value3
           g.leave()
        })

        g.notify(queue: .main) {
            completion(sum)
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thread 11: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x101d63f20) error where the first g.leave() line

Comment: `enter()` should be invoked equal number of times as `leave()`.

Comment: @MichelRivera i missed copying `g.enter()` check edit